# Should I mention a small platform in a query letter?

Tags: agent

I run a very small encyclopedia website that gets ~1k visitors per day. My articles have been cited by CNN, NBC, and The Independent (i.e., my website was one of twenty links that articles from these platforms included)

I just finished writing a historical fiction novel that takes place in the time period that my website focuses on.

Is it worth mentioning this when querying literary agents? I know that my platform isn't huge... But it isn't negligible, either.

I want my query letter to be short and to the point, and I'm not sure whether agents will care about anything less than 100k followers on Twitter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your particular case, I think it's definitely worth a mention. A thousand visitors a day, to a website that is relevant to your novel - it's both a potential platform for selling your book, and a good endorsement that you know what you're talking about.

The only times I'd advise an author *against* this:

1. Their platform is nothing to do with their novel
2. Their traffic is minimal

Keep it short and snappy, but most agents would be happy to hear about yours.

Comment: I agree, having an existing platform is absolutely vital to the querying process. Most agents I know will not even consider an author without a platform of some kind.